# Python: Parsing json list

Tags: json

HI guys I basically want to parse this json data.

```
[
    {
        "id": 417862,
        "name": "octokit.rb",
        "full_name": "octokit/octokit.rb",
        "owner": {
            "login": "octokit",
            "id": 3430433,
            "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/3430433?v=4",
            "gravatar_id": "",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit",
            "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit",
            "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/followers",
            "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/following{/other_user}",
            "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/gists{/gist_id}",
            "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
            "subscriptions_url": 
        } ]
```

My question is how do I get the value of `"id": 417862` from json

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language/library are you using?

Comment: I am using python!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
mylist = [{
  "id": 417862,
  "name": "octokit.rb",
  "full_name": "octokit/octokit.rb",
  "owner": {
    "login": "octokit",
    "id": 3430433,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/3430433?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octokit/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "cats"
  }
}]

print mylist[0]['id']
```

This returns prints the `id` attribute of the 0th (i.e. first) member of `mylist`, which equals `417862`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are using pandas:

create a function and return the 1st value of list,

```
def get_json_data(mylist):
    return mylist[0]
```

Create a new column and apply the function:

```
df['new_col']=df.apply(lambda df: get_json_data(df['old_col']),axis=1)
```

Once you get the data, just normalize it:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df['new_col'])
```

Hope this helps :)